# Upgrade to SpringBoot 2.5.0 GA - lost all metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot

Small issue after upgrading from SpringBoot 2.4.4 to SpringBoot 2.5.0.
My web application have the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And before the upgrade, I would get metrics like those fine

```
system_cpu_usage
jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes
jvm_threads_states_threads
jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes
logback_events_total
```

Unfortunately, after the bump to the 2.5.0 GA which just got released, no code change whatsoever, I lost all metrics. Still seeing some http time etc, but pretty much lost everything else

May I ask what is the issue please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a [bug in Spring Boot 2.5.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26665) that will get fixed in 2.5.1.